# Use sp_executesql with dynamic arguments

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserDetails
(
    @ParameterListWithDataType  VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ParameterNameList      VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ParameterValues        VARCHAR(MAX),
    @WhereCondition     VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = ' SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, Salary FROM UserDetails WHERE ' + @WhereCondition 

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParameterListWithDataType, @ParameterNameList
END

EXEC GetUserDetails @ParameterListWithDataType = '@FirstName VARCHAR(100)',  @ParameterNameList = '@FirstName', @ParameterValues = 'ABC', @WhereCondition = 'FirstName = @FirstName '

EXEC GetUserDetails @ParameterListWithDataType = '@FirstName VARCHAR(100), @LastName VARCHAR(100)',  @ParameterNameList = '@FirstName,@LastName', @ParameterValues = '''ABC'', ''XYZ''', @WhereCondition = 'FirstName = @FirstName OR LastName = @LastName'

EXEC GetUserDetails @ParameterListWithDataType = '@FirstName VARCHAR(100), @LastName VARCHAR(100), @MiddleName VARCHAR(100)',  @ParameterNameList = '@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleName', @ParameterValues = '''ABC'', ''XYZ'', ''DEF''', @WhereCondition = 'FirstName = @FirstName OR LastName = @LastName OR MiddleName = @MiddleName'
```

Is there any method to do like this? Because the Search criteria will be dynamic. Please give your comment or give me the alternate solution to use `sp_executesql` with dynamic number of parameters.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not use a view? This seems to only make it more complicated to filter without any benefit.

Comment: @adrianm I dont get your points. Because the columns to be used for search criteria will be dynamic. I dont know how to use view to achieve this.

Comment: `Nvarchar` for `@ParameterListWithDataType`. And normal solution would be: static sql, optional predicates and `option(recompile)`.

Comment: The caller of the procedure must format 4 strings for the filter. Why can't the caller just select from a view and apply the filter directly? `SELECT * FROM GetUserDetailsView WHERE FirstName = 'ABC'`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query helps you,.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserDetails
(
    @FirstName  VARCHAR(MAX),
    @LastName      VARCHAR(MAX),
    @MiddleName        VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @WhereCondition VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @WhereCondition = ' WHERE 1 = 1'+case when @FirstName is null then '' else ' or FirstName = '+ @FirstName end+
                            case when @LastName is null then '' else ' or LastName = '+ @LastName end+
                            case when @MiddleName is null then '' else ' or MiddleName = '+ @MiddleName
                          end

    SET @sql = ' SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Address, Salary FROM UserDetails' + @WhereCondition 

    EXECUTE(@sql)

END
```

Simply execute the procedure using

```
EXEC GetUserDetails 'ABC','XYZ','DEF'
```

Comment: I tried this approach already. But in order to avoid SQL Injection I need to use sp_executesql. Because when I give the below input for your procedure it will drop our table.                                                                                         EXEC GetUserDetails 'a', '', ''''';drop table Person--'